# What is the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^{\log x}}{c^x}$ where $c > 1$?

Tags: calculus, limits

My intuition tells me the answer is 0, but I can't figure out how to prove it. I've tried using L'Hopital's rule $k$ times in a row, but since $c^x$ doesn't change when being derived, this doesn't lead me anywhere.

I've also tried doing a Taylor expansion of $c^x$ before applying L'Hopital, but can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is equivalent to the limit
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{\ln^2{(x)}-x\ln{(c)}}=0$$
which is zero because $x\gt\gt\ln^2{(x)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $x^{\log(x)}=e^{\log(x)^2}$

Comment: Two Mathjax tips: (1) if you have nested powers, you need {curly braces} to specify the order of the powers; (2) if you've got a power consisting of more than one letter (e.g. \log(x) ), you need curly braces around the power.

Comment: The exponent for the log is ambiguous: it  can be interpreted as the log of $x^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder :), my mathjax has gotten all rusty.